# How can I create a shortcut/bookmark to "create a new note" in Evernote?

Tags: evernote, bookmarks

I want to press just one button on my browser (or desktop) and have it bring up the "new note" page on Evernote.com so I could quickly jot down ideas.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which Browser do you want to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an icon on my bookmark bar in Chrome that opens up a new note.

I use the link: https://www.evernote.com/edit?newNote

Works for me!

Answer (score 2):

Evernote web clipper information can be found here;

http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web_clipper.php

Device specific links are here;

http://www.evernote.com/about/download/all.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a good temp solution, but what I'm looking for is a quick way to bring up a place to write a long note. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

If Evernote is running (even in the background), you can use the global hotkey/shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to switch to Evernote and start a new Note. This works even when on browser is the active window.

OK, this is not just one button, but 3 buttons, but you can setup a new global hotkey as well (setup a one-button global hotkey in Windows)

See [the shortcuts support page](http://www.evernote.com/about/support/3.5_Shortcuts.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

i use an autohotkey script as quicklaunch shortcut :

; sends Evernote's "new note" keyboard shortcut then exits
send ^!n
ExitApp